# How can I change the way that VAT number is show using QWeb in Odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

I have the view `report_invoice_document` showing the VAT client number, using next code:

```
<span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/>
```

However, the number that appears is CO8000000001 and I need just the number without letters and if it's possible formatted this way 800.000.000-1.

I was trying to find documentation about t-field-options to customize the field but I didn't have luck with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<span t-esc="o.partner_id.vat[2:]"/>
```

`t-esc` supports Python code.